# CssSyntaxError in plugin "gulp-postcss" / You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser

Tags: sass, gulp, gulpfile

I'm using this plugin for years now, and it's the first time I get this error.
I'm working on an old project which i recently upgraded to the latests versions of node & npm, so I'm working with node `v16.15.0` and npm `v8.5.5`. I also upgraded all of my npm packages to their latests versions (yes, I like to live dangerously).

Gulp `v4.0.2` with `gulpfile.js` as such (there is some commented code in it because I'm still in the process of making it work with these versions of node & npm. Originally, this project was running fine with node `v12.6.0` and npm `v7.20.03` .
After upgrading, I encountered many errors, as for example the need to switch from `node-sass` to `dart-sass`, because it's deprecated. ) :

```
// MODULES
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    //sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('dart-sass'), require('node-sass')),
    sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'), require('dart-sass')),
    globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    stylelint = require('gulp-stylelint'),
    svgstore = require('gulp-svgstore'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    cssnano = require('cssnano'),
    uglifyjs = require('uglify-js'),
    del = require('del'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    // This is based on node-sass, which is deprecated
    // find a replacement which works with something else...
    //inliner = require('sass-inline-svg'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    openBrowser = require('open');

// Basic config for paths (cfg = config)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const cfg = {
  scssDir: 'src/scss/',
  builtCssDir: 'dist/css/',
  scssPattern: '**/*.scss',

  svgDir: 'src/assets/svg/',
  compiledSvgDir: 'dist/svg/',
  compiledSvgFileName: 'symbols.twig',
  svgPattern: '**/*.svg',

  jsLibsDir: 'src/js/libs/',
  jsDir: 'src/js/',
  compiledJsLibsDir: 'dist/js/libs/',
  compiledJsDir: 'dist/js/',
  jsPattern: '*.js'
}

// Launch a server
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function serve() {
  connect.server({
    port: 8080, 
    livereload: true,
    root: ['src']
  });
}

// Open application in browser
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function open() {
  await openBrowser('http://localhost:8080/');
}

// Construct style.css (Combine all scss files into one css final file)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function style() {
  return gulp
  .src(cfg.scssDir+cfg.scssPattern)
  // Test files with `gulp-stylelint` to ckeck the coding style
  /*.pipe(stylelint({
    reporters: [
      {formatter: 'compact', console: true}
    ]
  }))*/
  /*.pipe(sass({
    importer: globImporter(),
    functions: {
      svg: inliner(cfg.svgDir, {encodingFormat: 'uri'})
    }
  }))*/
  .on('error', sass.logError)
  // Use postcss with autoprefixer and compress the compiled file using cssnano
  .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(cfg.builtCssDir))
}

// Construct svg symbol file (Combine svg files into one with <symbol> elements)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*function svg() {
  return gulp
  .src(cfg.svgDir+cfg.svgPattern, {base: cfg.svgDir})
  .pipe(rename((filePath) => {
    const name = filePath.dirname !== '.' ? filePath.dirname.split(filePath.sep) : []
    name.push(filePath.basename)
    filePath.basename = `symbol-${name.join('-')}`
  }))
  .pipe(svgstore({ inlineSvg: true }))
  .pipe(rename(cfg.compiledSvgFileName))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(cfg.compiledSvgDir));
}*/

// Catch JS libs and transfer it to dist folder
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function jslibs() {
  return gulp
  .src(cfg.jsLibsDir+cfg.jsPattern)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(cfg.compiledJsLibsDir));
}

// Compile JS 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function js() {
  return gulp
  .src(cfg.jsDir+cfg.jsPattern)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(cfg.compiledJsDir));
}

// Watcher
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function watch() {
  gulp.watch('../'+cfg.scssDir+cfg.scssPattern, style)
  gulp.watch('../'+cfg.scssDir+cfg.scssPattern)
  gulp.watch(cfg.scssDir+cfg.scssPattern, style)
  gulp.watch(cfg.svgDir+cfg.svgPattern, svg)
  gulp.watch(cfg.scssDir+cfg.scssPattern);
}

// Empty the build folder of its front asset like css & svg (We're not emptying it totally, because there is other assets in it)
function clean() {
  return del([
    cfg.builtCssDir,
    cfg.compiledSvgDir+'/'+cfg.compiledSvgFileName,
    cfg.compiledJsDir
  ], {force: true});
}
clean.description = 'Delete the content of the build folder.';

// Serve
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Launch server

const launch = gulp.series(open, serve);

// Builder
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regenerate the build folder.

const build = gulp.series(clean, style, jslibs, js);

// Export default task
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regenerate the build folder & launch watcher
const defaultTask = gulp.series(clean, style, jslibs, js, watch);

// Export Tasks
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
module.exports = {
  open,
  serve,
  launch,
  clean,
  style,
  jslibs,
  js,
  build,
  watch,
  default: defaultTask
};
```

I get the following error when I try to throw my `gulp` default task in my terminal :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfyWp.png)

```
[11:42:55] CssSyntaxError in plugin "gulp-postcss"
Message:
    /Users/emma/Desktop/www/photosbroth/src/scss/styles.scss:3:1: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser

  1 | @charset "UTF-8";
  2 |
> 3 | // Import EXTERNAL libs
    | ^
  4 | // - `sass-mq` for breakpoints management
  5 | @import '../../node_modules/sass-mq/mq';
```

Apparently, it doesn't like the `//` scss comments, which were perfectly fine before I tried to upgrade my stack.

Could anyone help please ? I wasn't able to find a solution to this.

I tried this in the gulpfile :

`postcss = require('gulp-postcss')(require('postcss'))`

this

`postcss = require('gulp-postcss')(require('postcss-scss'))`

and this

`postcss = require('gulp-postcss')(require('postcss'), require('postcss-scss'))`

None of those expressions worked.

Is this a bug or anything else ? Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm having problems with this too. Missing something silly, no doubt. Any ideas?